# Copy n elements of const int std::array into an int vector. How to do it?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have in my code a `array<const int, 4> reference` and I would like to copy the first three elements of this array to a `vector<int> nvector`. So I tried to use `copy_n` like below but I'm getting segmentation fault when I run the program.

```
copy_n(reference.begin(), 3, nvector.begin());
```

This array is only for consulting. I'll never change it's elements. But with a certain condition, i would like to copy and return the first three elements of it. But if this condition is not satisfied I will copy and return the 4 elements of it. That is why it needs to be vector. Because my function will return an vector of 3 or 4 of those elements of array.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `nvector` is empty, use [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::copy_n(reference.begin(), 3, std::back_inserter(nvector));
```

Comment: @BenVoigt You are right, `back_inserter` is good for preserving the content, too. Since OP uses `nvector.begin()` in his example, I figured he's probably going for the copy into an initially empty vector. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure that `nvector` has at least three elements.

```
nvector.resize(3);
copy_n(reference.begin(), 3, nvector.begin());
```

You may also use [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

```
copy_n(reference.begin(), 3, std::back_inserter(nvector));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the vector to contain only the 3 elements:

```
nvector.assign(reference.begin(), reference.begin() + 3);
```

If you want to prepend the three elements to existing vector contents:

```
nvector.insert(nvector.begin(), reference.begin(), reference.begin() + 3);
```

If you want to append the three elements to existing vector contents:

```
nvector.insert(nvector.end(), reference.begin(), reference.begin() + 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your vector is empty before the `copy_n`.

If that's true,you can use the `std::back_inserter()`,which returns a `back_inserter_iterator`,and your code would be like

```
copy_n(reference.begin(), 3, std::back_inserter(nvector));
```

Unlike the common `push_back()` operations,the `back_inserter_iterator` will not be invalidated,so it's save for you to insert the element.

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering my own question because I found a different solution of you guys.
The thing is just set a size to this vector in the constructor.

```
 vector<int> nvector( 3 );
 copy_n(reference.begin(), 3, nvector.begin());
```

No need std::back_inserter.

Comment: then what if you're going to copy 4 elements?